# Does there always exists a path $g:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $f(0)$ to $f(1)$ that has the same image as $f$ and …?

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, path-connected

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ is a path in $X$ with non-zero finite length $L$. Then, does there always exist a path $g:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $f(0)$ to $f(1)$ that has the same image as $f$ and satisfies $\operatorname{Length}(g\rvert_{[0,t]})=tL$  for all $t \in [0,1]$?

Any views would be really appreciated.

Comment: But if $g(t)$ is constant for $t$ in some interval $J\subset [0,1]$, then the length of $g$ on $[0,t]$ is also constant for $t$ in the same interval $J$.

Comment: @PietroMajer Would you like to check a link. It contains a proof but i think it's incorrect.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696001/prove-that-there-exists-an-another-path-g-with-the-same-image-as-f-but-lengt

Comment: If $f:[0,1]\to (X,d)$ is continuous and has finite total variation $L=L([0,1],f)$, then  the length $L([0,t],f)$ is continuous wrto $t$. If  $f$ is constant on no open non-empty interval, then $L([0,t],f)$ is also strictly increasing, thus an increasing homeo $[0,1]\to[0,L]$. Its inverse gives an arc-length parametrization $[0,L]\ni t\mapsto f(g(t)$ with $L([0,s],f\circ g)=s$ for all $0\le s\le L$.  Check e.g. the nice book *Cours d'Analyse (tome II - Topologie)* by Gustave Choquet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard result that every rectifiable curve in a metric space admits an arc length parametrization. The proof can be found in many sources. For examples Theorem 3.2 in
[Hajłasz - Sobolev spaces on metric-measure spaces](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/OriginalPublications/Hajlasz-SobolevSpaces-ContempMath-338-2003-173-218.pdf). Then the arc-length parametrization is defined on $[0,L]$ and a linear change of variables leads us to $g$ defined on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Would you like to check a link. It contains a proof but i think it's incorrect.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696001/prove-that-there-exists-an-another-path-g-with-the-same-image-as-f-but-lengt