# Is the function $g$ always injective where $g$ is obtained by lipschitz re-parametrization

Tags: metric-spaces, path-connected

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space with the nearest point property and $a,b \in X$ with $a \ne b$. Suppose there is a path of finite length in $X$ from $a$ to $b$ and let $m$ be the infimum of the lengths of all paths from $a$ to $b$.Then, by  Lipschitz reparametrization, there exists a path $g:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $a$ to $b$ that satisfies $lth_t(g) = tm ~\forall~t \in [0,1].$ and $g$ is lipschitz with length $m. lth_t(g)$ represents the length of the function $g$ upto a point $t$.

Then is the function $g$ always injective?

I am kind of stuck here and can't think of any counterexamples as well. Any inputs will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The minimizng path $g$ may not exists. If it exists, then it must be injective (if it would not be then you could shorten it). (You do not need "nearest point property" no matter what is its meaning.)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin thanks. Could you help me prove injectivity

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin nope. It is not. I saw this as an open question posed by searcoid in a book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is injective because if $g(s)=g(t)$, $s<t$, then you can remove the interval $[s,t]$ from the domain of definition of $g$ and make the curve shorter. Then you rescale the domain to be $[0,1]$. Rescaling does not change the length of the curve. See also Lemma 3.10 in my notes linked to the answer to another related question: [does there always exists a path $g:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ from $f(0)$ to $f(1)$ that has the same image as $f$ and ..?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295446/does-there-always-exists-a-path-g0-1-rightarrow-x-from-f0-to-f1-th?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks but the problem posed mentions $[0,1]$ as the domain. Aren't we altering the conditions of the problem by changing the domain?

Comment: @MathMan I edited my answer to address your concern.

Comment: okay. which means the answer to the problem posed is : $g$ may not be always injective but there exists one $g$ which is injective obtained by shortening the curve?

Comment: It is injective since it is the shortest one. My argument was by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not because of the reason in the accepted answer. If you remove the portions where $g$ is constant, the length stays the same, you're not making it shorter. Instead, if there was such an interval, then the condition that ${\rm lth}_t(g) = tL$ would be violated since the LHS is constant on the interval in case, while the RHS isn't.